# How to prevent ListView from showing data before filtering

Tags: android

I use the following code to filter my `ArrayAdapter` and I call `setAdapter` after the filtering is done.  For some reason the unfiltered data flashes on the screen before the filter is applied.  Any ideas?

```
    mList = getData();
    Collections.sort(mList);

    mAdapter = new CustomItem(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, mList);

    String filter = mSpinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    mAdapter.getFilter().filter(filter);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Here's the code in my custom Filter:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter()
{
    return new Filter()
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
        {
            mSubItems = (ArrayList<CustomItem>)results.values;
            if (results.count > 0)
            {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else
            {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
        {
            setFilter(constraint);

            List<CustomItem> filteredResults = getFilteredResults();
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredResults;
            results.count = filteredResults.size();

            return results;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Try notifydatasetinvalidated, or doing your custom filter

Comment: I have my custom filter.  I'll post that code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to do some fancy footwork to make this look the way you want.  When the user first selects a filtering option you could remove the listView content.

Then use a FilterListener on the filter to know when filtering is complete and show the listView content again.

```
mAdapter.getFilter().filter(chars, new Filter.FilterListener() {
                public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
                   // show the listView content again;
                }
            });
```

Comment: This worked, I just waited to initially set the ListView's adapter until `onFilterComplete`.  Thanks!